# Java Reflection API - Getting the value of a String[] field

Tags: java, arrays, string, reflection

I was wondering if it is possible to grab a String[] of an unknown size from a class using the java reflection API and store it elsewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you do it with _String[]_ just like with any other type.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Foo {
  private String[] bar;

  public Foo(String[] bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Foo foo = new Foo(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"});
    Field barField = Foo.class.getDeclaredField("bar");
    String[] bar = (String[]) barField.get(foo);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bar)); // [a, b, c]
  }
}
```

In addition to `getDeclaredField(String)`, there's `getField(String)` and `getFields()` which only return public fields as well as `getDeclaredFields()` for all fields a class declares.